# Import a python Class from another sub-directory of parent directory

Tags: python

So I'm trying to do some stuff with Json, and so I want to be able to acces the Dragoon Class (in Dragoon.py) from the Character_manager.py file.
Here's what my folder looks like.

```
- Code
    - Classes
        - Arbalist
        - Bard
        - Character (every other class extends from this)
        - Dragoon
        - Guardian
        - Seraph
        - Slaughterer
        - Spellcaster
    - Data
        -  Account_manager.py
        - Accounts.json
        - Character_manager.py
        - Characters.json
```

So I tried using a couple of solutions found on the internet, but most of them where only working for either Python2 or to import from Parent Directory only.

If I forgot to specify anything, please let me know!

Edit:
Some of you asked about what is the point of the code, so here is when I would use the dragoon import.

```py
print("Choose a profession")
print("1. Dragoon")
choice = input("Choice: ")
        match (choice):
            case "1":
                character = Dragoon()
            case _:
                character_manager(username) #Go back to the previous menu
```

Someone also suggested to regroup every Class into the Character.py file, which doesn't sound like a bad idea and it's probably what I will be doing (I'm used to have one class per file with Java).
I'll then try to import the new Character.py as a whole, and shouldn't be a problem anymore. (I'll update/answer when done)

For my own culture, would anyone still be able to answer the first issue?

Comment: _If I forgot to specify anything_ Show us the actual code of `Character_manager.py`, and show us exactly how you run the code.

Comment: It is crucial to understand, the relative position of some module with respect to another *isn't really important*. What is crucial is *what directory is in the import path*. It isn't clear here what directory is in the import path. For a project like yours, you would generally put `Code` in the import path (giving it a more descriptive name). And generally, this would be done by *packaging* your project, and then *installing it* (perhaps, in editable mode if you are still working on it).

Comment: also, as an aside, it is very atypical in Python to have a module for every class. I would just put all those classes in a single module, called something like `character.py`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using sys to add Classes to the system path

```
# import sys
import sys

# adding Classes to the system path
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/you/Code/Classes')

# import Dragoon
from Dragoon import functionA, functionB
```

You would need to specify you actual path.

Comment: this is really not the right way to go about this

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer after a lot of research and random testing.
I've moved every class in my Character.py file and have my Code/ folder containing the Classes/ and Data/ folder, respectively having Character.py and Character_manager.py

Here's the answer I came up with:

```py
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'Classes'))

from Character import Dragoon, Arbalist, Slaughterer, Guardian, Spellcaster, Bard, Seraph
```

Comment: You should not do this